# how to make the list data into formatted json in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, formatting

the list data looks like this:

```
[
    "message: // System.out.println(\"resultMap -- \"+resultMap);--->1.0",
    "category: Poor Logging Practice--->1.0",
    "message: // System.out.println(\"resultMap -- \"+resultMap);--->1.0",
    "category: Cross Site Scripting--->1.0",
    "message: // System.out.println(\"resultMap -- \"+resultMap);--->1.0",
    "category: Poor Logging Practice--->1.0",
    "message: // System.out.println(\"\" + bean.getBlockId());-->0.507092552837",
    "category: Denial of Service--->1.0",
    "message: * System.out.println(objects[0]); Long l =--->0.507092552837",
    "category: Cross Site Scripting--->1.0"
]
```

I want the above list data to be converted to json which should look like this:

```
[
   {
    "message: // System.out.println(\"resultMap -- \"+resultMap);--->1.0",
    "category: Poor Logging Practice--->1.0"
   },
   {
    "message: // System.out.println(\"resultMap -- \"+resultMap);--->1.0",
    "category: Cross Site Scripting--->1.0"
   },
   {
    "message: // System.out.println(\"resultMap -- \"+resultMap);--->1.0",
    "category: Poor Logging Practice--->1.0"
   },
   {
    "message: // System.out.println(\"\" + bean.getBlockId());-->0.507092552837",
    "category: Denial of Service--->1.0"
   },
   {
    "message: * System.out.println(objects[0]); Long l =--->0.507092552837",
    "category: Cross Site Scripting--->1.0"
   }
]
```

**Note:I have already tried json.dumps() but it dint work!!**

Comment: Your desired output is a list of set?

Comment: @Rakesh i guess he means a json array of json objects

Comment: this is the formatted json that we use for development

Comment: That is not valid JSON. Do you mean `{"message": "// System...", "category": "Poor..."}`?

Comment: @JoelBerkeley yes exactly

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, it should be {
    "message": " // System.out.println(\"resultMap -- \"+resultMap);--->1.0",
    "category": "Poor Logging Practice--->1.0"
   }

Comment: please update question with desired output

Answer (score 1):

Using list slicing.

**Ex:**

```
lst = [
    "message: // System.out.println(\"resultMap -- \"+resultMap);--->1.0",
    "category: Poor Logging Practice--->1.0",
    "message: // System.out.println(\"resultMap -- \"+resultMap);--->1.0",
    "category: Cross Site Scripting--->1.0",
    "message: // System.out.println(\"resultMap -- \"+resultMap);--->1.0",
    "category: Poor Logging Practice--->1.0",
    "message: // System.out.println(\"\" + bean.getBlockId());-->0.507092552837",
    "category: Denial of Service--->1.0",
    "message: * System.out.println(objects[0]); Long l =--->0.507092552837",
    "category: Cross Site Scripting--->1.0"
]

res = []
for i in range(0, len(lst), 2):       
    message, category = lst[i:i+2]
    res.append({"message": message.lstrip("message:"), "category": category.lstrip("category:")})
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'category': ' Poor Logging Practice--->1.0',
  'message': ' // System.out.println("resultMap -- "+resultMap);--->1.0'},
 {'category': ' Cross Site Scripting--->1.0',
  'message': ' // System.out.println("resultMap -- "+resultMap);--->1.0'},
 {'category': ' Poor Logging Practice--->1.0',
  'message': ' // System.out.println("resultMap -- "+resultMap);--->1.0'},
 {'category': ' Denial of Service--->1.0',
  'message': ' // System.out.println("" + bean.getBlockId());-->0.507092552837'},
 {'category': ' Cross Site Scripting--->1.0',
  'message': ' * System.out.println(objects[0]); Long l =--->0.507092552837'}]
```

Comment: Replaced it to `lstrip`